# Execute PHP script after php-fpm master process is restarted

Tags: php, caching, server, fpm

Say I have a script to populate the PHP APC cache when PHP is restarted, the cache is empty.

Is it possible to create a mechanism to autorun some kind of script when the master php-fpm process is started?

Comment: Are you using Linux and able to alter the service init script?  if you're not able to find an answer on SO, I recommend asking your question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) instead, as you're looking to do additional tasks when a server process is started.

Answer (score 3):

Open php-fpm

```
vim /etc/init.d/php-fpm
```

In the file, find the start function, add your commands at the end.

```
start () {
    ...
    # Your commands here
}
```

Save and restart php-fpm

Answer (score 1):

**I have one article for you please once read it, It might be helpful to you [Link](https://ma.ttias.be/a-better-way-to-run-php-fpm/)**

Open php-frm through CMD

**Ubantu** `sudo gedit /etc/init.d/php-fpm`

You put the code under following function.

```
function start {
   /* 
     Your code here
   */
}
```